# Save AWS API output as CSV getting TypeError as NoneType or Blank

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, csv

```
 **COLUMN A**                                                 **COLUMN B**

[{TimePeriod: {Start: 2020-03-01    
 End: 2020-04-01}
```

I have a script that pulls data from AWS. AWS automatically puts in the info with the data when running this command. How do I get just the amount from column A and have it look like Column B? Column B is my manual input and Column A is from AWS output. Is there something I can add to my script to only output the Amount?

Comment: Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```py
    results += data['ResultsByTime']
```

With:

```py
    for info in data['ResultsByTime']:
        for group in info['Groups']:
            results.append(float(group['Metrics']['AmortizedCost']['Amount']))
```

If you simply wish to **print** the results, and include the Linked Account, use:

```py
    for info in data['ResultsByTime']:
        for group in info['Groups']:
            print(group['Keys'][0], group['Metrics']['AmortizedCost']['Amount'])
```

To also show the dates:

```py
    for info in data['ResultsByTime']:
        for group in info['Groups']:
            print(group['Keys'][0], info['TimePeriod']['Start'], info['TimePeriod']['End'], group['Metrics']['AmortizedCost']['Amount'])
```

Comment: **Left to right:** I followed your code example, where you were adding the numbers to a list called "results". You could alternatively print the value instead of adding it to a list, or output the list to a CSV using the csv library. That is up to you. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I'll let you figure out how to add the date. Take a look at the [`get_cost_and_usage()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ce.html#CostExplorer.Client.get_cost_and_usage) documentation and scroll down to the "Returns" section to see the data that is provided (or just `print(data)` in your code). You'll see the date inside the `TimePeriod`. It's just a matter of navigating to the element. Use the code from my answer as an example of how to get to the right element.

Comment: I've added something that should work. You'll notice the dates come from `TimePeriod`, which is at the same level as `Groups`.

Comment: Thank you. I've been trying to export the results as a CSV but I keep getting a TypeError or a blank CSV. How would I be able to achieve this?

Comment: You could either print a comma between each value (in the `print()` statement) and save the output to disk, or you could use the `csv` Python module to create a file. (Look for examples of that in other StackOverflow questions.)

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a way to add an input function to Metrics but the problem is it needs to identify the input when I'm doing the data =... I have Metrics=[input("AmortizedCost or UnblendedCost?\n")] and then I have data=(group['Keys'][0], info['TimePeriod']['Start'], group['Metrics']['AmortizedCost']['Amount'], group['Keys'][1]) so what would be the best way to use an input function into Metrics for the data part?

Comment: @shaheed313 Please create a new question rather than asking via a comment on an old question.